# What is the best UI Java markup language for designing applications for Google Android?

Tags: java, xml, android, markup

What is the best (meaning: most popular) UI Java markup language for **designing** applications for Google Android?

So i will say something like

```
<Application layout="vertical">
 <Panel width="250" height="200" layout="vertical" horizontalAlign="center" 
 verticalAlign="middle" title="This is a panel">
  <Button label="This is a button"/>
 </Panel>
</Application>
```

and get something like

[image: this window]
<sub>(source: [vdrillpro.net](http://www.vdrillpro.net/blogs/flex_2/example_app.PNG))</sub>

Comment: There are more than one? News for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, the [Android one](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/index.html)? I'm not aware of any alternative either.